# Transform values of a dict in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Hello I have a dictionary python like this :

```
a = {'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
```

And I would like to have this :

```
a = {'b':[1], 'c':[2], 'd':[3]}
```

How can I do this to have this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
a = ['1', '2']
for i in a:
    for j in range(int(i), int(i) + 2):
        d[j].append(i)
```

usage:

```
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: ['1'], 2: ['1', '2'], 3: ['2']})
>>> d.items()
[(1, ['1']), (2, ['1', '2']), (3, ['2'])]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}
a = {k:[v] for k, v in a.items()}

print(a)
```

Prints:

```
{'b': [1], 'c': [2], 'd': [3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
>>> a = dict([(i,[j]) for i,j in a.items()])
>>> a
{'b': [1], 'c': [2], 'd': [3]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For in-place modification, you could use:

```
a = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}


for k, v in a.items():
    a[k] = [v]


print(a)
# {'b': [1], 'c': [2], 'd': [3]}
```

---

This should come out as slightly faster than creating a new dictionary:

```
def listify(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        d[k] = [v]
    return d


def listify2(d):
    return {k: [v] for k, v in d.items()}


a = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
print(listify(a))
# {'b': [1], 'c': [2], 'd': [3]}

a = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}
print(listify2(a))
# {'b': [1], 'c': [2], 'd': [3]}


%timeit a = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}; a = listify(a)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 522 ns per loop
%timeit a = {'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'd': 3}; a = listify2(a)
# 1000000 loops, best of 3: 660 ns per loop
```